# linear algebra - finitely generated

Tags: linear-algebra, finitely-generated

I have to prove that:

If the space V is finitely generated, all the generating systems of V are finite.

Therefore, I have tried doing the following: I know that if V is finitely generated, exists a finite generator system of V and V has got a finite basis. I also know that if V is not {0}, all the bases of V have the same dimension. But I don't really get a solid conclusion.

I also have an other idea, which I'm not sure it's ok: If V is finitely generated, we supposed that $\dim V=n$. As the dimension of the generator system has to be equal or bigger that $\dim V$, the proposition is false. (?)

Comment: That is false: $V$ itself is  a generating system.

Comment: Whose giving you these exercises? Not even an hour ago you asked this community to prove another completely false statement.

Comment: What is your definition of "generating system" (as opposed to "generating set")?

Comment: For me, a generating system is a group of vectors which are able to form a base by combining between them(not necesarily free)

Comment: So they are the same as what is generally called "generating sets" or "spanning sets".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prove it, since it is false. The whole space $V$ itself is a generating set of $V$ and, in general, it is infinite.

Comment: I don't surely understand it. If V is finitely generated, V could be infinite???

Comment: What's the proble. The real vector space $\mathbb R^2$ is an infinite set, right?! However, it is finitely generated, since it is generated by the set $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$.